# how to broadcast/multicast a service over the network for clients to discover without any need for server IP

Tags: ip-address, broadcast, service-discovery, autodiscovery

how to broadcast/multicast a service over the network for clients to discover without any need for server IP?

how to let other clients discover the service from a server, without the client requiring the IP address of the server, similar to DHCP IP acquiring.

broadcast? multicast? how do i implement the same in ruby or any other language?

Comment: Have a look at how UPNP works.

Answer (score 0):

WS-Discovery is a protocol intended for this purpose. It has a few different variations, different flavors of broadcasting and proxies. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Discovery

.NET WCF4 implements this. I suspect some other languages/stacks may as well.